# Загрузка массива на бд(phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

Ребят, помогите. Я новичок и стараюсь понять все что тут написано(вроде как).
Подскажите как загрузить Массив на бд(phpMyAdmin). Может мне нужно посмотреть пару уроков? Если да, то каких. Спасибо за ранее. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Answer (score 0):

сложно понять, но если вы пытаетесь отправить массив напрямую в бд, то не выйдет.

Можете преобразовать в пхп массив в строку функцией `implode("|",$type);`
где 1 аргументов передается сепаратор, а вторым массив. и функцией `explode($type,"|")`
Сможете преобразовать назад, при импорте из бд.

Comment: Здраствуйте, спасибо что ответили.
У меня удалось запушить массив в бд через connect->query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `user_id`, `title`, `body`) VALUES (NULL, '$value', '', '')"); где $value - это элемент массива.
Только пока не могу разобраться как запушить одновременно все элементы.

Comment: $value - это 1 строчный эллемент литбо строка либо число.
Вам необходимо сначала преобразовать массив в строку. и уже строку отправлять в базу. База не умеет хранить массивы.

На мой взгял лучше всего использовать 
$str = serialize($array); и уже $str Отправлять в запрос.

А когда будете вытаскивать то преобразуйте назад $array = unserialize($str);